# Is there a reason behind the 'Ending' joke?

Tags: book-adaptation, it-chapter-two

Throughout *It (2019): Chapter Two* there is a running joke where people keep making fun of the ending of Bill Denborough's book. This is brought up by the people making the film of the book as well as Stephen King himself (in his cameo).

Is this a kind of in-joke? Was Stephen unhappy with his own ending of *It*? I ask because of course the movie changes the ending of the book (just as the producer in the movie was proposing to change Bill's ending), and of course there is the infamous sex scene which would understandably make an author squeamish and was thankfully also left out.

So my question is, is this joke in the movie a reference to the ending of *It* itself?

Answer (score 10):

The joke is about Stephen King himself, he receives a lot of criticism for his weak book endings, here's one example:

You can find a lot of discussions on this topic on the internet.

Answer (score 8):

## The bad endings reflect Bill's view on the world.

The endings are considered bad because they are sad. At some point in the movie (I can't find the script, or subtitles as of this date) Bill complains to the dislikers that his endings, although bad, are realistic.

> Life isn't always a fairy tale, and things don't always end happily.

This reflects Bill's look on life, he thinks it is dark, gloomy, sad, and won't end well, all because of his past trauma with It and his brother Georgie. By the end of the movie, his attitude changes and he has a better attitude towards life, and he can see a glimmer of hope in the horizon.

> I just finished the first chapter. And I think now I know how to end it.

The book describes Bill's thoughts after all his adventures very nicely:

> Best to believe there will be happily ever afters all the way around—and so there may be; who is to say there will not be such endings? Not all boats which sail away into darkness never find the sun again, or the hand of another child; if life teaches anything at all, it teaches that there are so many happy endings that the man who believes there is no God needs his rationality called into serious question.

Comment: An extra reason to mention that people hate the ending is that it helps emphasize how important Mike's call is: Bill's flight to Derry puts the whole movie production (which is usually a multi-million dollar investment) in jeopardy.